# db2/AS400 SQLException Token Was not valid

Tags: db2-400

I am trying to solve possible **SQL volnurability with AS400 Transfer**. One of solution is to change query by adding encoding. 
EX:`"select * from address where city='bellevue'  "`  will be replaced by : `"select * from address where city=''bellevue''   "`. That query throws exception :`java.sql.SQLException:[SQL0101]Token bellevue was not valid. Valid tokens:FOR....`  **Oracle**, **MySQL** seems to have no problem executing the same type of query, but **DB2 /AS400** doesn't like it.  Query works great with only one "'". Using **JDBC** connection with driver : **com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver**. Any idea why?

Comment: Q: You can successfully use a single quote ('), correct?  If so, what's the problem?

Comment: Correct , single quote works fine. I am trying to secure query by escaping user's input ( see link: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). They perfect solution would be to use PreparedStatement, but in our case query generates by users typing, so parsing query and generating PreparedStatement is a bit costly. Escaping is another way and this is why we are replacing single quote with 2 single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to prevent SQL injection.  It looks like you have seen a sugestion to replace a single apostrophe (`'`) with two apostrophes (`''`).  But they were talking only about the content of the user's input, not around it.

Let's take a look at how such a attack might work. You give the user a field where you want to let them enter the name of a city.  You want to use that value in your query.

```
query := "select * from address where upper(city)=upper('" || input_city || ")'"
```

And then you will send this query string to be interpreted by the database server.  Everything is fine if they enter `bellvue` or `NEW YORK`. But think about what happens if they enter  `Washington's Crossing` then you've got a problem. The first part of your query string ends in an apostrophe to start the string literal, but the apostrophe in the name of the city will ends the literal and the `s Crossing` will cause a syntax error.

Now imagine what could happen if someone knew about this, and got creative with their input? Let's look at a few.

```
x' or '1'='1
'; select * from tablescatalog where table_name >'
'; delete from customers where name<>'
```

or some other values that might do worse. Now you can see why it is the input field that needs the special attention when building a query dynamically.   You need to process specious characters before using it in your query string.

Alternatively, you could PREPARE a parameterized query.  This is generally a safer method.  It performs much better too.

Comment: [comic](https://xkcd.com/327/)  and the [explanation](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I agree that PrepareStatement with parameterized query is saver and better performed. Our application allows user to maually type WHERE clause(user will type WHERE CITY='BELLEVUE') . Do you know any open source product which will convert user input to parameterize query? I was looking at SQL Parser, but it is commercial product.

Comment: You supply the query, with a question mark as a place marker for the parameter. You prepare that statement, then execute it (or open it as a cursor) supplying the user input as the parameter value(s).  Since it's already been prepared, the syntax has already been determined; the user's input cannot be interpreted as anything else.